# Get current time in iOS without internet

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Is there any way we can get current time of the user based on the location without connecting to internet and irrespective of the device time?? tried with DateTime and it always returns device time.

Comment: as much as i know location in apple devices too uses internet so i dont think so, if no internet you cannot get server based time.

Comment: Isn't it the responsibility of the device to update its clock (even based on the location)? You can't assume the device did not adjust the internal clock before the internet connection was lost. Only thing you could do is get the location, compare it with the timezone that location is in (should be an offline/local database) and compare the Date's location against that....

Comment: no, there is no other way to get it

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately** , there is no other way .

From [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1591574-date?language=objc) , get current time is from this :

> NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

in Xamarin write as follow ：

```
NSDate currentdate = new NSDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date()` will return the current time from your phone time.

Code(swift):

```
let now = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
print("time string：\(formatter.string(from: now))")
```